# Storing user data securely in Flutter and Dart

Tags: flutter, dart, encryption

Suppose I have a notes app where I need to store user's notes securely. Can I store the notes in a plaintext format in an sqlite database? Or should they be encrypted locally as well?

Also should I encrypt it before I send it to the Firestore database? I've looked into the [encrypt package](https://pub.dev/packages/encrypt) but it's difficult to understand. Are there any good tutorials for this?

If I should encrypt, what type of encryption should I use?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Consider the usage of [hive](https://pub.dev/packages/hive), which is a very popular NoSQL database for Dart and Flutter which automatically does a strong encryption of the data.

It's also used by the [hydrated_bloc](https://pub.dev/packages/hydrated_bloc) for example and other packages.

---

In general, you shouldn't implement encryption/decryption logic by yourself. Use well-known libraries (such as hive) which just does the work for you.

Comment: Hi I'm wondering about data being sent off device for example to Firestore

Comment: You don't need to send encrypted notes via Firestore since it's already a secure HTTPS connection. It's already encrypted by construction. You shouldn't store passwords in clear so sending encrypted passwords is generally the best thing to do. Ok, Firestore "is safe" but still you shouldn't store sensible data in clear.

Comment: That's good to know! I'm not sending any passwords. And other than Hive are sqlite databases generally secure?

Comment: If you mean "secure = encrypted" then no, sqlite databases are not automatically encrypted. You still need to entrypt data by yourself

Comment: Is it necessary to encrypt non sensitive data stored in sqlite databases?

Comment: Yes. With SQLite you should use something to encrypt your passwords (MD5, SHA-1...) but you have to look for a reliable one.

Comment: So even non sensitive information stored in an sqlite database should be secured with a password?

Comment: It depends on you, there is not a general rule. Passwords for sure shouldn't be in clear but the rest, it depends

Comment: Where would I store the encryption key for the hive, isn't that just moving the problem? With the key and the hive storage dumped the data is accessible. I know data is stored securely by apps out there so it should be possible but I'm not sure how that is

Answer (score 1):

I dont think you need to encrpyt before you send it to firestore.. As long as you set your firestore rules well it would be ok

Comment: But I can see their data as the admin...isn't that unsafe?

Comment: you can block everyone including yourself

Comment: Oh wow, I didn't know that! And do I need to encrypt the data stored in sqlite databases on device?

Comment: yh its pretty easy should i give you a link where you can learn more about rules

Comment: https://fireship.io/snippets/firestore-rules-recipes/

Comment: Thanks! And do I need to encrypt the data stored in sqlite databases on device?

Comment: please can you upvote my answer.. Well i dont think so .. You can just put an extra layer of security. Like a password page.. Which is really easier

Comment: thanks if you need help with a password page i can help

Comment: Thanks, I have a password page

Answer (score 1):

I guess including encryption depends on the type of data you're storing. Whether it is sensitive etc. same yada yada rules apply even in flutter. Like you should encrypt passwords etc.
I you're going for encryption I highly suggest to encrypt the data even using dart before sending it to firebase or as some http request/response.
Check out this package-
[flutter_string_encryption](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_string_encryption)

[xxtea](https://pub.dev/packages/xxtea)